# Why this different behaviour while indexing the array using character?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dictionary

I am trying to write a c++ program to find the first non-repeated character and if all the characters are repeated it would return -1.

I have designed a solution that keeps track of the count of characters using a integer array which I index using the respective character whose count has to be stored.

Program 1:
Gives erroneous output...
http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/wxOYog

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int map[256];
string returnFirstRepeatingChar(string str,int n)
{
    int i=0,flag=1;
    string result;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        map[str[i]]++;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(map[str[i]]==1)
        {
            flag=0;
            result = str[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        return "-1";
    else
        return result;
}
int main()
{
    //code
    int t,N,*arr,i,j;
    cin>>t;
    string str;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>N;
        memset(&map,0,256);
        cin>>str;
        cout<<returnFirstRepeatingChar(str,N)<<endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Program 2:
Gives correct output...
http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/jJvJPu

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int map[256];
string returnFirstRepeatingChar(string str,int n)
{
    int i=0,flag=1;
    string result;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        map[str[i]-97]++;           //changed from above program

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(map[str[i]-97]==1)       //changed from above program
        {
            flag=0;
            result = str[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        return "-1";
    else
        return result;
}
int main()
{
    //code
    int t,N,*arr,i,j;
    cin>>t;
    string str;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>N;
        memset(&map,0,256);
        cin>>str;
        cout<<returnFirstRepeatingChar(str,N)<<endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Only difference between the two programs is location of required counts in the array map..
In the program 1, it starts from 97 (ascii of a)
In the program 2, it starts from 0.

But program 2 gives correct output, but the program 1 isn't. Why?

```
Eg: for input: abcdefghij
program 1 output: f
program 2 output: a
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Desired behaviour is clearly given in the form of second implementation. All I need is an explanation for that...

Comment: ... **in the question itself**

Comment: @PavithranRavichandiran, You can't expect people to click links to websites they've never heard of, nor expect that link to stay valid indefinitely, nor expect Google to be able to direct other people with the same problem to the question when a lot of it is hidden away. All of that aside, SO has its rules and it's courteous to follow them when using the site.

Comment: Okay. Can someone please edit the question in a right way...I tried the same and I can't get the indentations right... I agree to @chris but I unable to do the same

Comment: @PavithranRavichandiran: There are plenty of text editors around that help with indentation. When you're done just indent the whole thing by another 4 spaces and paste it to the SO textbox.

Comment: Okay. Now edited properly. Will any mercy be shown to me?

Comment: @PavithranRavichandiran: yes, mercy was shown to you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One important issue here is this line:

```
memset(&map,0,256);
```

Here you are zeroing only the first 256/sizeof(int). In case the sizeof(int) is 4, this makes the first 64 int.
However, your program is using the elements which index is greater than 97, hence the issue appearing.
Hence it should be

```
memset(&map,0,256*sizeof(int));
```

or could be also simply written as

```
memset(map,0,sizeof(map));
```

Remember: the 3rd parameter of memset is "the number of bytes to fill", not "the number of elements of your array"

Comment: That second example should be `memset(&map,0,256*sizeof(int));` as `sizeof(int)` is not guarenteed to be 4.

Comment: @user1937198: thanks for your remark, i corrected it